# Looking for Personal Lexicon / Dictionary software

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, vocabulary, dictionary, software

I'm trying to find a personal lexicon/dictionary/language study/flash card program - preferably one that makes allowances (ie has a place to enter) all of the forms of a word (noun declensions, verb tenses etc).

The closest thing I've been able to find is [Personal Lexicon](https://www.personal-lexicon.com/) which lets you add these forms, but never asks you about them.

[iVocabulary 3](https://apps.chbeer.de/ivocabulary/) which is based on [ProVoc](http://www.arizona-software.ch/provoc/) also looked very promising but not quite there.

I'm certain I've seen software that does this (and by certain I mean I might have imagined it), does anyone know of a program or have any suggestions?

Just to recap, I am hoping to find language learning / lexicon software that:

1. Lets you create your own entries.
2. It allows for the great number of forms Latin has for it's conjugations and declensions etc.
3. I can use software on the following platforms (in order of preference) - MacOS, iPadOS, Windows, Java/Web apps etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do try Anki:
https://apps.ankiweb.net/
I have been using it for 5+ years to study/improve my knowledge of languages and to prepare for exams. It has an impressive toolkit, and additionally supports audio (quite useful for the purpose), as well as images/videos and LaTeX (speaking of exam preparation). It is available on all platforms and is free (with a notable exception of iOS where it's $25, I believe, for whatever reason).

Comment: https://kde.org/applications/education/org.kde.parley has similar functionalities but much smaller user base, so there are not as many ready-made courses that can be downloaded off the shelf.

Comment: I am happy to type every entry for the vocabulary that I’m looking to work with so lack of pre-existing courses are not an issue